# event.preventDefault() appears to not work for me within a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events, keyup

I have some simple Angular 7.x code that basically uses a contenteditable div where I am trying to prevent the default action when a user presses the [ENTER] key - the code appears fine but no matter what I seem to try it does the default action e.g moves the cursor to the next line which I am trying to prevent from happening.

What am I doing wrong?

// component code

```
onTextChange(event): void {
    // keyCode for the Enter key is 13
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log('enterPressed');
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

// template code

```
<div contenteditable="true" [(ngModel)]="text" (keyup)="onTextChange($event)" (change)="onTextChange($event)" #textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `keypress` or `keydown`, which is caught at the moment user presses key, instead of "after" user has already pressed the key. Also you should get an error in console trying to use `ngModel` on a div. You can catch the value with `$event.target.innerText` instead:

```
onTextChange(event): void {
  // keyCode for the Enter key is 13
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log('enterPressed', event.target.innerText);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div contenteditable="true" (keydown)="onTextChange($event)">
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t3khcq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Faster by one minute :D I will delete my answer

Comment: @karoluS, haa... sometimes that happens :P

Answer (score 2):

In Angular, you can directly use it like `(keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"`

```
<div contenteditable="true" [(ngModel)]="text" (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" #textarea></div>
```